# SVG - which difference between <set> element and <animate> element?

Tags: svg

I have seen the following [demo](https://www.javatpoint.com/svg-set-element) using a specific SVG's `set` element.
The example's snippet also implements the SVG `animate`'s element.

Abstractly I would assume that the `animate` and `set` element would be two different `versions` of a same function, but since they are in the same snippet I assume they fill different functions.

The SVG documentation is very elusive concerning the proprieties of a possible SVG's `set` element. So how are we suppose to use it and what are its particularities?

source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/set
w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#SetElement

thanks for any hint

Comment: What is unclear about the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#SetElement)?

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for your answer. I am wondering why just dont use the animate element anew, like in the following example: https://codepen.io/joondoe/pen/LYYRegv?editors=1000